# dart vm - improving performace for reading json and http communication

Tags: dart

I am comparing dart to nodejs.

I rewrote nodeJs app to parse and return to http client huge chunk of json (around 1000 objects). for test purpose json is read from file. then json is parsed to Map, transformed to new representation and responed to client.

**the sample app can be found here [mapping json sample app](https://bitbucket.org/fourtyfourblocks/dartanian/src/69e2e6fe2e8ef30e3cc61df9f6312eec1916399e/examples/json-mapping/?at=develop)**

when I increase number of concurrent calls to service I notice increase of response time.

here is ab report for 10 concurrent threads processing 40 requests

```
document Length:        613480 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   9.079 seconds
Complete requests:      40
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      24542960 bytes
HTML transferred:       24539200 bytes
Requests per second:    4.41 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2269.770 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       226.977 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          2639.89 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.8      0       5
Processing:  1250 2111 300.0   2126    2880
Waiting:     1024 1917 307.9   1948    2840
Total:       1255 2111 299.6   2126    2880

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%   2126
66%   2213
75%   2233
80%   2243
90%   2446
95%   2865
98%   2880
99%   2880
100%   2880 (longest request)
```

notice how response time drops if using only 2 concurrent threads

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:   279  447 140.9    415    1033
Waiting:      224  397 140.1    405    1000
Total:        279  447 140.9    415    1033

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%    415
66%    422
75%    430
80%    434
90%    463
95%   1007
98%   1033
99%   1033
100%   1033 (longest request)
```

and when there is only one client it is super fast

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.1      0       1
Processing:   189  207  14.7    205     265
Waiting:      186  205  14.5    203     262
Total:        189  207  14.7    205     265

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%    205
66%    209
75%    214
80%    217
90%    224
95%    240
98%    265
99%    265
100%    265 (longest request)
```

**And here is ab output for node running on the same data and same machine**

```
Document Length:        807396 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   3.955 seconds
Complete requests:      40
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      32304320 bytes
HTML transferred:       32295840 bytes
Requests per second:    10.11 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       988.661 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       98.866 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          7977.25 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.5      0       3
Processing:   954  987  18.6   1000    1007
Waiting:      116  567 272.1    598     999
Total:        954  987  18.7   1001    1007

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
50%   1001
66%   1004
75%   1004
80%   1004
90%   1005
95%   1005
98%   1007
99%   1007
100%   1007 (longest request)
```

I understand that if I put many events on the event queue response time increases. but I expected that dart uses microtasks to handle waiting events earlier.

here is data sample, result array always contains 1000 items

```
{
    "numFound": 1234,
    "results": [
        {
            "cid": "id",
            "cir": "id",
            "cn": "name",
            "cbr": "string",
            "crn": "string",
            "dep": "string",
            "depid": "id",
            "fn": "string",
            "jvid": "id",
            "loc": "string",
            "pid": "id",
            "date": int,
            "toe": "string",
            "ujn": "string",
            "vn": "string",
            "ind": "string",
            "indid": "id",
            "fun": "string",
            "funid": "id",
            "des": "string",
            "date2": int,
            "uuid": "string",
            "elv": "string",
            "elvid": "id",
            "cfv": Array<Objects>
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using centos 6.5 (I have builded dart 1.2 sdk). I run app with

> perf record -g -- dart --generate_perf_events_symbols start.dart

and here is what 'perf report --call-graph flat' shows but I'm not sure how to interpret output to improve my code any how.

```
    75.86%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __do_softirq
+   3.62%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::MarkingVisitor::VisitPointers(dart::RawObject**, dart::RawObject**)
+   1.36%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::ScavengerVisitor::VisitPointers(dart::RawObject**, dart::RawObject**)
+   1.02%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::GCSweeper::SweepPage(dart::HeapPage*, dart::FreeList*)
+   0.96%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:core_StringBuffer_writeCharCode
+   0.74%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__Utf8Decoder@0xda80e0a_convert
+   0.71%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__JsonStringifier@0xda80e0a_escape
+   0.57%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__Utf8Encoder@0xda80e0a__fillBuffer@0xda80e0a
+   0.55%  dart  libc-2.12.so         [.] _wordcopy_fwd_aligned
    0.53%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] retint_careful
+   0.52%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:core_StringBuffer__addPart@0x36924d72
    0.50%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] finish_task_switch
    0.49%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::RawObject::VisitPointers(dart::ObjectPointerVisitor*)
    0.41%  dart  [vsyscall]           [.] 0x000000000000014c
    0.38%  dart  libc-2.12.so         [.] memmove
    0.29%  dart  libpthread-2.12.so   [.] pthread_getspecific
    0.29%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::FreeList::TryAllocate(long, bool)
    0.28%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] dart:core__List@0x36924d72__List@0x36924d72.
    0.28%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__JsonParser@0xda80e0a_parse
    0.27%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:core_StringBuffer_write
    0.27%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *package:public-api/publicApi.dart_PostingResultMapper_mapPosting_mapPosting
    0.27%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] _spin_unlock_irqrestore
    0.27%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::String::Copy(dart::String const&, long, unsigned char const*, long)
    0.27%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::VMHandles::AllocateHandle(dart::Isolate*)
    0.26%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:collection__HashMap@0x23c35ea0&&_LinkedHashMapMixin@0x23c35ea0_forEach
    0.25%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__JsonStringifier@0xda80e0a_stringifyJsonValue
    0.24%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::Object::Allocate(long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
    0.24%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] dart:core__StringBase@0x36924d72_codeUnitAt
    0.23%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::GCMarker::DrainMarkingStack(dart::Isolate*, dart::MarkingVisitor*)
    0.22%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::ClassTable::UpdateLiveOld(long, long)
    0.22%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__JsonParser@0xda80e0a_parseString
    0.21%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__JsonParser@0xda80e0a_parseString
    0.20%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::String::Copy(dart::String const&, long, dart::String const&, long, long)
    0.17%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::OneByteString::ConcatAll(dart::Array const&, long, long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
    0.16%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __do_page_fault
    0.16%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_StringBase_substringUnchecked(_Dart_NativeArguments*)
    0.15%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::String::ConcatAllRange(dart::Array const&, long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
    0.15%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:core_StringBuffer__consumeBuffer@0x36924d72
    0.14%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] clear_page_c
    0.13%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] _stub_OneArgCheckInlineCache
    0.12%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:core__StringBase@0x36924d72_substring
    0.11%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::String::Copy(dart::String const&, long, unsigned short const*, long)
    0.11%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:collection__HashMap@0x23c35ea0&&_LinkedHashMapMixin@0x23c35ea0__addEntry@0x23c35ea0
    0.11%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::String::SubString(dart::String const&, long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
    0.11%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::FreeList::SplitElementAfterAndEnqueue(dart::FreeListElement*, long, bool)
    0.10%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] get_page_from_freelist
    0.10%  dart  dart                 [.] 0x000000000031b333
    0.10%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::Scavenger::ProcessToSpace(dart::ScavengerVisitor*)
    0.09%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::RawArray::VisitArrayPointers(dart::RawArray*, dart::ObjectPointerVisitor*)
    0.09%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::ClassTable::UpdateAllocatedOld(long, long)
    0.08%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::Profiler::RecordSampleInterruptCallback(dart::InterruptedThreadState const&, void*)
    0.08%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_String_concatRange(_Dart_NativeArguments*)
    0.08%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:convert__JsonStringifier@0xda80e0a_stringifyJsonValue_<anonymous closure>
    0.07%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] _stub_TwoArgsCheckInlineCache
    0.07%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_Object_getHash(_Dart_NativeArguments*)
    0.07%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:core__Smi@0x36924d72_toString
    0.07%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] dart:core__OneByteString@0x36924d72_get_hashCode
    0.07%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::Instance::IsInstance() const
    0.06%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_StringBuffer_createStringFromUint16Array(_Dart_NativeArguments*)
    0.06%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] *dart:collection_Maps_mapToString
    0.06%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::VMHandles::~VMHandles()
    0.06%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::GCMarker::MarkObjects(dart::Isolate*, dart::PageSpace*, bool, bool)
    0.06%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::PageSpace::TryAllocate(long, dart::HeapPage::PageType, dart::PageSpace::GrowthPolicy)
    0.06%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] free_hot_cold_page
    0.06%  dart  perf-5465.map        [.] dart:core__StringBase@0x36924d72__substringUncheckedNative@0x36924d72
    0.06%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::LoadOptimizer::Optimize()
    0.06%  dart  dart                 [.] dart::Heap::AllocateNew(long)
```

Comment: Can you make the code and JSON data available for example on a public github repo? It's hard to reason about some printed numbers without knowing more about the source. You could also post a link to [dart-misc Google group](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!forum/misc)  Ananlyzing performance problems often lead to discussions which isn't what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: yep so the server I wrote is here https://bitbucket.org/fourtyfourblocks/dartanian/src/ee1c2e48ef334bec634f1215a20db8a2958ac78d/?at=develop. the app is pretty simple but I guess I need to review it before publishing as this is company's internal stuff.

Comment: You should look at develop branch lib/src/rsServer.dart method _dispatch and lib/src/resource.dart and perhaps lib/src/defaultHandler.dart _UriResourceHandler

Comment: I ve added data sample to main question

Comment: I couldn't find the code of your test (start.dart). I wonder why you think using Microtasks would improve the response time. Microtasks are used delay execution within the current event to be executed before the control returns to the event queue. If you put larger tasks into the Microtask queues other events may got stale and response time will probably become worse. What is a thread for you? Dart has no threads. I saw a worker mentioned in your code. I know only isolates for parallel execution in Dart.

Comment: yes that is true, but you want to respond as quickly as possible to a client, even before handling next event. of course your queue may get larger but you can add another server. well both approaches would be valid.

Comment: I will add apps code shortly, but there is no big magic. it handles request using dartanian server, reads file, transforms json into Map, transforms each object and responds to client. from perf report I guess that the app is mostly waiting - 75.86%  dart  [kernel.kallsyms]    [k] __do_softirq

Comment: Isn't this the expected behaviour in both node and dart? i.e. you're parsing 600k of JSON on a single threaded server. This will block the event loop/isolate. If you want more parallelism you will need to split out the parsing into another worker/isolate, or run the server behind a load balancer.

Comment: yep but why node is faster on the same machine - doing exact same thing, I was promised that dart should be faster, or it will not be faster for this scenerio

Comment: I ve added sample app (@Günter Zöchbauer) https://bitbucket.org/fourtyfourblocks/dartanian/src/69e2e6fe2e8ef30e3cc61df9f6312eec1916399e/examples/json-mapping/?at=develop please run it from example/json-mapping/bin directory. you may also create log dir in example/json-mapping/

Comment: can someone explain what is __do_softirq doing? I cannot find something using google. I guess it is system waiting.

Comment: Seems this is the time the kernel takes (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sample_analysis_with_perf_report) I guess these are all the I/O operations (Not sure though, I have not much experience in these matters).

Comment: anyway Im going to rip code out from my dartanian server and ll see if I can gain any time. maybe node's fs.readFile is better optimized so dart's openRead needs some attention.

Comment: This is the results I'm seeing with 1.2:

-c 1: Requests per second:    266.26 [#/sec] (mean)
-c 16: Requests per second:    360.98 [#/sec] (mean)

and a little bit faster with bleeding edge.

Comment: probably on your machine results are going to be different. As you can see I had only 4 request per second, maybe this is something about vagrant and virtualbox. but why node on same machine, inside same vm guest performs 2 faster. I have build sdk from 1.2

Comment: I looked at your code but with all this abstraction (DI) it's hard to grasp how the app exactly works. I thing you should split the tasks in smaller parts and benchmark them to find out where the time is wasted (for example load JSON and decode it).

Comment: from what I ve looked at this, encoding and decoding is a blast. I'd rather suspect that I defer too much so individual client waits longer :(

Answer (score 1):

I just want sum up what I have found about the behavior of dart on vm. after asking directly it turn out that transforming is serious problem here.

this is already improved in latest build and should be included in next stable version as well.

please check this bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17659 and the conversation itself from drt google group https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/S0rGeyc9aQU

many thanks Gunter, Anders and Greg for trying to help me here.